# jquery mobile nav panel push only contents not header

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel, nav

I have been trying to modify the JQM library code to make the nav panel push only the content part not the header part. I acheieved it by chaning the code in

```
$.widget( "mobile.panel", {

_getWrapper: function() {
    var wrapper = this._page().find( "." + this.options.classes.pageWrapper );
    if ( wrapper.length === 0 ) {
        wrapper = this._page().children( ".Myheader, .ui-content:not(.ui-popup), .ui-footer:not(.ui-footer-fixed)" )
            .wrapAll( "<div class='" + this.options.classes.pageWrapper + "'></div>" )
            .parent();
    }

    this._wrapper = wrapper;
};
```

is there a way where i can do it by not changing library code, something like a monkey patch or create a panel in mobileinit?

Comment: What version are you doing this on? The docs say its possible to do this out of the box.

Comment: Please provide some inputs